# Using right DOM node for form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using a working script for my page to create accounts. Now i want to combine this script with the jquery wizard plugin. So i can't use anymore the this.form selector because i'm working in another function (or i'm at least wrong with that idea). Saddly i don't get the values to the function.

If someone need the whole script/source: http://beta.juuin.com/site/first_review/first_review.php

Part of the Working Script:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Send" onclick="return
regformhash(this.form, this.form.email,
this.form.password, this.form.confirmpwd);" />
```

Working regformhash():

```
function regformhash(form, email, password, conf) {var p = document.createElement("input");
form.appendChild(p);
p.name = "p";
p.type = "hidden";
p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
password.value = "";
conf.value = "";
form.submit();
return true;}
```

Part of the new Script wit the jquery Steps:

```
var form_wizard = $("#registration_form").show();

   form_wizard.steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "fieldset",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
        {
            // Allways allow previous action even if the current form is not valid!
            if (currentIndex > newIndex)
            {
                return true;
            }
            // Forbid next action on "Warning" step if the user is to young

            // Needed in some cases if the user went back (clean up)
            if (currentIndex < newIndex)
            {
                // To remove error styles
                form_wizard.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error").remove();
                form_wizard.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error").removeClass("error");
            }
            form_wizard.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
            return form_wizard.valid();
        },

        onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
        {
            form_wizard.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
            return form_wizard.valid();
        },
        onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
        {

        return regformhash2(form, form.email, form.password, form.confirmpwd)

            form_wizard.submit();

        return true;
        }
    }).validate({
        errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },

    });
```

The Form Tag

```
<form role="form" id="registration_form" method="post"
 name="registration_form" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
```

Comment: Is it possible you are setting form_wizard to a boolean result instead of the form because you are assigning it to a method result (.show())?

Comment: to be honest, i'm not sure why i need this first line with the show() I have this from the jquery-steps-wizard: http://www.jquery-steps.com

Comment: What does your <Form> tag look like?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: I think it might be your action. The examples they show uses "#" so that the form does not post anywhere. This makes sense since it is a Single Page Application architecture.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's looking good for the moment :) Still testing. Do i have to change big things if i'm one day want to use a processing page instead of a single page application?

Comment: It's still not working, for example i can put console.log(form_wizard) and console.log(form.input.email) to check the values. The first one get a result, the second one a undefinied. :(